# Difference between type variable and type parameter in the Wild FJ paper?

Tags: java, generics, types, wildcard, type-parameter

In the 2005 [Wild FJ](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/fool/program/final/14/14_Paper.pdf) paper by Torgersen, et al., the first paragraphs of sections 2 and 3 use the term "type parameter". Then the first sentence of section 3.1 introduces the term "type variable". Given the context in which it is discussed and the lack of info on Google, I can only surmise that "type variable" is used to refer to wildcards specifically. This is, I'm pretty sure, the "ground-breaking" paper that led to the implementation of wildcards in Java.

Edit: Big thanks to deduper for putting in the hard work of editing my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full text search reveals that "type variable" first occurs in section 2:

> As long as the element type is known at the call site, this may be expressed with plain generics using apolymorphic method with a dummy type variable:
>
> ```
> 〈X〉void m1(List〈X〉list) { ... }
> ```

As you can see, this example doesn't use wildcards at all, contradicting your assumption that "type variable is used to refer to wildcards specifically".

So, what *are* type variables? Since the term is not defined in the paper itself, it must be defined in one of its references.

But which one? Since it is customary to include references before the terms are first used, the reference must be in the introduction section, and from context, this sentence looks most promising:

> Parametric  polymorphism — also known as genericity or generics — originated in the world offunctional programming [21]

So we are likely to find the answer in

> [21] Robin Milner.  A theory of type polymorphism in programming. Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 17:348–375, August 1978.

Googling the title of that paper finds a PDF with the full text, and indeed, that classic paper contains numerous examples for type variables, such as:

> EXAMPLE 1.
>
> Mapping a function over a list.
>
> ```
> let rec map(f, m) = if null (m) then nil 
>                     else cons (f(hd(m)), map (f, d(m)))
> ```
>
> Intuitively, the function `map` so declared takes a function from things of one sort to things of another sort, and a list of things of the first sort, and produces a list of things of the second sort. So we say that map has type
>
> ((α → β) x α list) → β list
>
> where α, β are type variables.

So, a type variable is just a variable (in the mathematical sense) that will contain a type. A type variable can be introduced by a type parameter, but as Milner shows, type variables can also be introduced by other means. (Notice how α and β do not show up in the definition of `map`?)

Something similar happens when the Java compiler performs wildcard capture. For instance, if we write:

```
List<?> sourceList = ...;
List<?> targetList = ...;
targetList.add(sourceList.get(0));
```

the compiler says:

```
The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#2-of ?)
```

As we can see, when reasoning about wildcard types, the compiler "captures" the value of wildcards into fresh type variables such as `capture#1-of ?`. Unlike type variables introduced by type parameters, these type variables never show up in the source code.

And that is why, when discussing wildcard capture, the Wild FJ paper speaks about type variables not introduced by type parameters.

Comment: *"type variables such as `capture#1-of ?`"* --- `capture#1-of ?` is not a **type variable**. It is an anonymous description of a **type argument**. In Java's Runtime Library, the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface defines a type variable named `E`. In the quoted code at the top of this answer, `<X>` defines a type variable named `X`, and the `X` in `List<X>` is a type argument. In the code at the end of the answer, the two `?` are wildcard type arguments.

Comment: @Andreas: In the paper OP is asking about, wildcard capture *is* described to introduce new type variables, specifically, they write: "The type system of the Java programming language, takes a more radical approach, called “capture conversion”. The “open” process above is applied to every expression. The fresh type variables are made globally accessible, ...". That pretty clearly implies that capture conversion does create type variables, does it not? As for the rest of your comment, I know all that, but I fail to see how it pertains to OPs question?

Comment: I agree, I also fail to see how the last part of your question applies to the question, since the last part only shows *type arguments*, and the question is about the difference between *type parameter* and *type variable*. The error is basically just saying that the *type argument* of `sourceList` is incompatible with the *type argument* of `targetList`, when applied to the `add()` method. That has nothing to do with the question. `capture#1-of ?` and `capture#2-of ?` are the *values* of the *type variables*, as seen by the compiler. They are not themselves *type variables*.

Comment: Similar to the [`get(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method, where `0` is the *value* of the `index` parameter variable, for the [`List<?>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) generic, `?` is the "value" of the `E` type parameter, where the compiler names the `?` as `capture#1-of ?` for identification purposes.

Comment: It seems I have not expressed myself clearly. OP is puzzled about the meaning of "type variable" in section 3.1 of the Wild FJ paper. That section describes wildcard capture. That's why I include an example of what wildcard capture is, and contrast type variables introduced by wildcard capture with type variables introduced by declaring a type parameter.

Comment: In the paper, section 3.1, Box<? extends T> box; is given as an example. The sentence that follows this declaration states "The type of the expression box is then Box<Y> where Y <: T
is a globally fresh type variable." Is this saying that a wildcard type argument, such as the example, is converted to a fresh type variable <Y> because wildcards themselves are not type variables? The same is done with the example declaration preceding this that also contains a covariant type argument. I think that's what the section is saying

Comment: „*…`capture#1-of ?` is not a type variable…*“ – @Andreas — So why does the JLS call them type variables? – „*If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `?` then `Si` is a fresh **type variable** whose upper bound is `Ui`…*“ — [*§5.1.10 Capture Conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10). Type variables [*are specified to have bounds*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4-110). As §5.1.10 says, capture conversion-generated fresh type variables have bounds. They fit all of the criteria of that production in the JLS.

Answer (score 7):

In a method, `foo(int x)`, the following terminology is used:

- The method has 1 ***formal parameter*** (`int x`), though that is often shortened to *parameter*, leading to potential confusion. `int` is the *parameter type* and `x` is the *parameter name*.
- `x` is a ***parameter variable***, though that is often shortened to *parameter*, leading to potential confusion.
- In a call, `foo(5)`, the value is called an ***argument***, though that is often called a *parameter value*, shortened to *parameter*, leading to potential confusion. When clarification is needed, it is called an *actual parameter*.

As you can see, the shorthand use of the word *parameter* can mean `int x`, `x`, or `5`, depending on context.

For generic types, `Foo<X extends Number>`, a similar naming is used:

- The type has 1 ***type parameter***, where `extends Number` is the *type bound*, and `X` is the *type identifier*.
- `X` is a ***type variable***.
- When used, `Foo<Integer>`, the `Integer` part is called a ***type argument***. The type argument can be a wildcard.

Do not confuse a methods `parameter type` with a generics `type parameter`.

As you can see, your conclusion that *""type variable" is used to refer to wildcards specifically"* is incorrect. *Type variable* refers to the type parameters name, regardless of whether the type parameter is bound or not.

The "actual" type of the type variable, i.e. the type argument, may or may not be a wildcard, since that is specified in the use of the generic type, not in the definition of the generic type.

A generics *type variable* is only referenced in the definition of the generic type, similar to how a methods *parameter variable* is only referenced in the body of the method.

Comment: In the paper, section 3.1, Box<? extends T> box; is given as an example. The sentence that follows this declaration states "The type of the expression box is then Box<Y> where Y <: T is a globally fresh type variable." Is this saying that a wildcard type argument, such as the example, is converted to a fresh type variable <Y> because wildcards themselves are not type variables? The same is done with the example declaration preceding this that also contains a covariant type argument.

Comment: @MatthewS. What it's saying makes no sense to me, and it's wrong. *"By standard rules the type of `box.get()` is thus `Y`"* is wrong, because the type of `box.get()` is `T`, since there is no `Y`. --- Even if there was a `Y`, it is not a *type variable*, because `X` is the only type variable of the generic type `Box`. `Y` is the value of `X` (as seen by the compiler).

Comment: The paper is endorsed by authors of the Java SE near the end of section 4.5.1, in fine print. Not even joking, it's in fine print